# terminal_panel function not applied in plotting an glmertree object

Tags: r, party

I fitted a `glmtertree` model and like to apply a modified `node_barplot` function `my_node_barplot` for plotting. However, it seems that function `my_node_barpolot` is not passed to the `plot.constparty` function, resulting in using the `node_barplot` function shipped with package `partykit`.

Reproducible example from package `glmertree` vignette:

```
library("glmertree")
data("MHserviceDemo", package = "glmertree")
MHserviceDemo$outcome_bin <- factor(MHserviceDemo$outcome > 0)
MH_gtree <- glmertree(outcome_bin ~ 1 | cluster_id | age + gender +
                      emotional + autism + impact + conduct,
                      data = MHserviceDemo, family = "binomial")
plot(MH_gtree, which = "tree")
plot(MH_gtree, which = "tree", terminal_panel = my_node_barplot)
```

shows the same plot. `my_panel_barplot` is a slightly modified version of `panel_barplot` from GitHub, I changed the lines building the `mainlab` variable to print more information::

```
## ... skipped
function(id, nobs) sprintf("Node %s (n = %s)", id, nobs)
## rest skipped ...
```

to

```
## ... skipped
function(id, nobs, resp) {
      frq <- table(resp)
      perc <- round(frq[1]/sum(frq)*100, 1)
      sprintf("Node %s (n = %s)\n: %s%% (%s/%s)",
               id, nobs, perc, frq[1], sum(frq))
} else {
   function(id, nobs, resp) sprintf("n = %s", nobs)
   }
}
if (is.function(mainlab)) {
      mainlab <- mainlab(names(obj)[nid], nobs[nid], y)
} 
## skipped ...
```

The function has many lines, but when helpful I can post or share it.

Comment: Could you please add a simple self contained and reproducible example? Then I'll take a look.

Comment: thanks for taking a look at that!

Comment: added an example

Comment: Thanks, this helped to identify the exact problem and suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right the the `terminal_panel` argument is ignored in this specific setup. The reason is that the `plot()` method for `glmertree` objects mainly focuses on displaying trees that have a real regressor (e.g., a treatment variable) as part of the GLMM specification. In contrast, the case with an intercept-only regressor (as in your example) is passed on to `glmtree` which the uses coercion to `constparty` and applies defaults for that. This solution is very convenient if you accept the default but to pass on arguments we would have to replicate some of the code from `partykit` in `glmertree`. I will discuss with Marjolein, the lead author, whether this is worth the effort.

The workaround for your specific case is to do the coercion to `constparty` yourself. Subsequently you can use all the standard strategies for extending the plots of that, e.g.,

```
MH_ctree <- as.constparty(MH_gtree)
plot(MH_ctree, terminal_panel = my_node_barplot)
```

[image: constparty with custom my_node_barplot]

Note that I removed the line break within the `mainlab` which still works well for this particular plot. For plots with more terminal nodes you are likely to need the line break. Then you need to increase the number of lines for the `mainlab` as well.

Finally, rather than going through the internals of `node_barplot` you can also compose the `mainlab` outside of the tree and then insert it via the `mainlab` argument. See this post for a worked example:

[partykit: Displaying terminal node percentile values above terminal node boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314187/partykit-displaying-terminal-node-percentile-values-above-terminal-node-boxplot/33355897#33355897)

Comment: many thanks, that's really great and helps a lot!