# Changing terminal node in partykit

Tags: r, party, ctree

For illustration purposes, I try to modify the terminal node of a ctree in partykit.

I created some data and fitted an unpruned decision tree. Unsurprisingly the tree grows very large, and I have problems illustrating the tree properly.

Here is the code, where I created some data and then fitted the tree:

```
library(partykit)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# a function that creates some data for me

dgp_math_s <- function(ni,nj, RI_sd, sigma2 = 1,
                gamma00 = 0, gamma01 = 0, gamma10 = 0, gamma02 = 0, gamma20 = 0){
  
  dgp_grid <- expand.grid(
    ni = 1:ni,
    nj = 1:nj,
    gamma02 = NA,
    gamma20 = NA,
    studying = NA,
    atmosphere = NA,
    math_score = NA, # with two predictor variables
    Rij = NA,
    U0j = NA
  )
  
  dgp_grid$atmosphere <- rep(rbinom(nj,1,0.5), each = length(1:ni))
  #create a random factorial level 2 predictor z1j, same value for the whole cluster 
  
  dgp_grid$U0j <- rep(rnorm(nj, mean = 3, sd = RI_sd), each = ni)
  #create level 2 residual 
  
  dgp_grid$Rij <- rnorm(ni*nj, mean = 3, sd = sqrt(sigma2))
  # create level 1 residual with sigma2 = 1
  
  dgp_grid$studying <-sample(0:5, ni*nj, replace = TRUE)
  # create level 1 x1ij explanatory/predictor variable (draw from standard normal) 
  
  dgp_grid$math_score <-
    gamma00 + gamma10 * dgp_grid$studying + gamma01 * dgp_grid$atmosphere +
    dgp_grid$U0j + dgp_grid$Rij
  #creating yij with only two predictor without any effect

  return(dgp_grid)
}
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#fitting the tree

dgp_math<-dgp_math_s(ni = 20, nj = 20, RI_sd = 2, gamma10 = 0, gamma01 = 0)
#create data 

diab_model <- partykit::ctree(math_score~ studying + atmosphere, data=dgp_math, control = ctree_control(mincriterion=0.005, minsplit=0, minbucket=0))
#fit unpruned tree


plot(diab_model, gp = gpar(fontsize = 7))
#ploting the tree
```

When plotting the tree now it looks something like this:
[image]

As you can see, the text over the nodes is not entirely visible.
I tried to change the font size with `gp = gpar(fontsize = 7)`, but it was not enough. I also tried to change the terminal node with something like `terminal_panel = node_boxplot(id = FALSE)` but that didnt work either.

Any ideas on how I can change the text of the terminal node so that it does not show the n = xx part?

Or any other ideas on how I can improve the terminal node so that I can plot it nicely?

Thanks!

Comment: If my answer below solves the problem, please accept it by clicking the check mark on the left of it. Then SO flags it as resolved. If not, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node_*()` panel-generating functions need the fitted tree object as their first argument. Thus, to set `id = FALSE` you would have to do:

```
plot(diab_model, terminal_panel = node_boxplot(diab_model, id = FALSE))
```

In order not to repeat the object name (here: `diab_model`) one can also use the terminal panel arguments `tp_args` which is particularly convenient when you use the default panel function anyway (here: `node_boxplot()`). Thus, the following is equivalent to the call above:

```
plot(diab_model, tp_args = list(id = FALSE))
```

For the most flexible formatting of the main label you can use the `mainlab` argument. It can be a `function(id, nobs)` and then you can decide if/how these are shown. A compact display would be "id: n=..." which I set up below. Additionally I reduce the amount of space between the terminal panels:

```
mylab <- function(id, nobs) sprintf("%s: n=%s", id, nobs)
plot(diab_model, tp_args = list(mainlab = mylab, ylines = 1.5))
```

[image: ctree plot with custom mainlab and reduced ylines]

Instead of setting the font size, I have simply plotted the display onto a large device of 15 x 8 inch.

The following discussion provides an example how you can further customize the `mainlab`: [partykit: Displaying terminal node percentile values above terminal node boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314187/partykit-displaying-terminal-node-percentile-values-above-terminal-node-boxplot)